# PYQT How to edit the title of QDockWidget which is tabifyed in MainWindow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.centralContent = QtGui.QMainWindow()

        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralContent)

        self.centralContent.firstTabWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.centralContent.firstTabDock = QtGui.QDockWidget("first")
        self.centralContent.firstTabDock.setWidget(self.centralContent.firstTabWidget)
        self.centralContent.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea,self.centralContent.firstTabDock)
        self.centralContent.secondTabWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.centralContent.secondTabDock = QtGui.QDockWidget("second")
        self.centralContent.secondTabDock.setWidget(self.centralContent.secondTabWidget)
        self.centralContent.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea,self.centralContent.secondTabDock)

        self.centralContent.tabifyDockWidget(self.centralContent.firstTabDock, self.centralContent.secondTabDock)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Here is my sample code. I would like to edit the title of DockWidget ('first','second') with mouse double click. Is there any sample or class for this problem?

Comment: try: `self.centralContent.firstTabDock.setWindowTitle("Your Title")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a PyQt4 port of the solution by @JosephIreland (with a few refinements):

```
class DockTitleBar(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, dockWidget):
        super(DockTitleBar, self).__init__(dockWidget)

        boxLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        boxLayout.setSpacing(1)
        boxLayout.setMargin(1)

        self.titleLabel = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.titleEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.titleEdit.hide()
        self.titleEdit.editingFinished.connect(self.finishEdit)

        iconSize = QtGui.QApplication.style().standardIcon(
            QtGui.QStyle.SP_TitleBarNormalButton).actualSize(
                QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
        buttonSize = iconSize + QtCore.QSize(4, 4)

        self.dockButton = QtGui.QToolButton(self)
        self.dockButton.setIcon(QtGui.QApplication.style().standardIcon(
            QtGui.QStyle.SP_TitleBarNormalButton))
        self.dockButton.setMaximumSize(buttonSize)
        self.dockButton.setAutoRaise(True)
        self.dockButton.clicked.connect(self.toggleFloating)

        self.closeButton = QtGui.QToolButton(self)
        self.closeButton.setMaximumSize(buttonSize)
        self.closeButton.setAutoRaise(True)
        self.closeButton.setIcon(QtGui.QApplication.style().standardIcon(
            QtGui.QStyle.SP_DockWidgetCloseButton))
        self.closeButton.clicked.connect(self.closeParent)

        boxLayout.addSpacing(2)
        boxLayout.addWidget(self.titleLabel)
        boxLayout.addWidget(self.titleEdit)
        boxLayout.addStretch()
        boxLayout.addSpacing(5)
        boxLayout.addWidget(self.dockButton)
        boxLayout.addWidget(self.closeButton)

        dockWidget.featuresChanged.connect(self.onFeaturesChanged)

        self.onFeaturesChanged(dockWidget.features())
        self.setTitle(dockWidget.windowTitle())

        dockWidget.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.WindowTitleChange:
            self.setTitle(source.windowTitle())
        return super(DockTitleBar, self).eventFilter(source, event)

    def startEdit(self):
        self.titleLabel.hide()
        self.titleEdit.show()
        self.titleEdit.setFocus()

    def finishEdit(self):
        self.titleEdit.hide()
        self.titleLabel.show()
        self.parent().setWindowTitle(self.titleEdit.text())

    def onFeaturesChanged(self, features):
        if not features & QtGui.QDockWidget.DockWidgetVerticalTitleBar:
            self.closeButton.setVisible(
                features & QtGui.QDockWidget.DockWidgetClosable)
            self.dockButton.setVisible(
                features & QtGui.QDockWidget.DockWidgetFloatable)
        else:
            raise ValueError('vertical title bar not supported')

    def setTitle(self, title):
        self.titleLabel.setText(title)
        self.titleEdit.setText(title)

    def toggleFloating(self):
        self.parent().setFloating(not self.parent().isFloating())

    def closeParent(self):
        self.parent().toggleViewAction().setChecked(False)
        self.parent().hide()

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        if event.pos().x() <= self.titleLabel.width():
            self.startEdit()
        else:
            # this keeps the normal double-click behaviour
            super(DockTitleBar, self).mouseDoubleClickEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        event.ignore()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        event.ignore()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        event.ignore()
```

Comment: What a great code! I just add [self.titleLabel.hide()] to avoid title overlab. it's a big help for me! Thx!

Answer (score 3):

This is a reasonably involved piece of work, but thats what you get when you need to replace the default qt parts. It might be easier to just add a button/menu item somewhere which launches a dialog, and calls `QDockWidget::setWindowTitle()`; You could also install an event filter on the `QDockWidget` and catch double click `QMouseEvent`s to launch a dialog.

Anyway it's perfectly doable, if a little involved.

### Summary

You can create a new title bar widget for the dock widget (see http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdockwidget.html#setTitleBarWidget).

For the title, use a `QLabel` and `QLineEdit` adjacent in a layout, and toggle visibility on double click / `QLineEdit::editingFinished` such that only one is visible at a time.

Connect `QLineEdit::editingFinished` to a new slot which sets the window title, and `QDockWidget::windowTitleChanged` to a slot which sets the text for the `QLabel` and `QLineEdit`.
You'll also need to initialise them to parent window title on construction and on changeEvent(QEvent::ParentChanged).

You would also have to reimplement the close/dock buttons which is probably a pain, but is doable. You would need to `q_object_cast` `parentWidget()` to a `QDockWidget` and check `QDockWidget::features()` for which buttons to show, and connect them to the right slots on construction, and parent changed. You can use toolbuttons with icons from `QStyle::StandardPixmap`

Good luck

edit: managed to bang this out on my lunch break. It acts just like the original title bar, except double clicking replaces the title label with a QLineEdit.

### Example in C++ Qt5 (should be easy enough to port)

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QToolButton>
#include <QStyle>
#include <QDockWidget>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QBoxLayout>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QAction>


// usage: dockwidget->setTitleBarWidget(new EditableDockTitleBar(dockwidget));
class EditableDockTitleBar : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit EditableDockTitleBar(QDockWidget *parent): QWidget(parent) {
        parentDockWidget = parent;

        auto boxLayout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
        boxLayout->setSpacing(1);
        boxLayout->setMargin(1);
        setLayout(boxLayout);

        titleLabel = new QLabel(this);
        titleEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
        titleEdit->hide();
        connect(titleEdit, &QLineEdit::editingFinished, this, &EditableDockTitleBar::finishEdit);

        QSize iconSize = QApplication::style()->standardIcon(QStyle::StandardPixmap::SP_TitleBarNormalButton).actualSize(QSize(100,100));
        QSize buttonSize = iconSize +  QSize(4,4);
        dockButton = new QToolButton(this);
        dockButton->setIcon(QApplication::style()->standardIcon(QStyle::StandardPixmap::SP_TitleBarNormalButton));
        dockButton->setMaximumSize(buttonSize);
        dockButton->setAutoRaise(true);
        connect (dockButton, &QToolButton::clicked, this, &EditableDockTitleBar::toggleFloating);
        closeButton = new QToolButton(this);
        closeButton->setMaximumSize(buttonSize);
        closeButton->setAutoRaise(true);
        closeButton->setIcon(QApplication::style()->standardIcon(QStyle::StandardPixmap::SP_DockWidgetCloseButton));
        connect (closeButton, &QToolButton::clicked, this, &EditableDockTitleBar::closeParent);

        boxLayout->addSpacing(2);
        boxLayout->addWidget(titleLabel);
        boxLayout->addWidget(titleEdit);
        boxLayout->addSpacing(5);
        boxLayout->addWidget(dockButton);
        boxLayout->addWidget(closeButton);

        auto* dockWidget = parentDockWidget;

        connect(dockWidget, &QDockWidget::featuresChanged, this, &EditableDockTitleBar::onFeaturesChanged);
        connect(dockWidget, &QDockWidget::windowTitleChanged, this, &EditableDockTitleBar::setTitle);

        onFeaturesChanged(dockWidget->features());
        setTitle(dockWidget->windowTitle());

    }

public slots:
    void startEdit() {
        titleLabel->hide();
        titleEdit->show();
        titleEdit->setFocus();
    }
    void finishEdit() {
        titleEdit->hide();
        titleLabel->show();

        parentDockWidget->setWindowTitle(titleEdit->text());

    }

    void onFeaturesChanged(QDockWidget::DockWidgetFeatures features) {
        closeButton->setVisible(features & QDockWidget::DockWidgetClosable);
        dockButton->setVisible(features & QDockWidget::DockWidgetFloatable);
        Q_ASSERT_X(! (features & QDockWidget::DockWidgetVerticalTitleBar), "DockTitleBar::onFeaturesChanged", "vertical title bar not supported");
    }

    void setTitle(const QString& title) {
        titleLabel->setText(title);
        titleEdit->setText(title);
    }

    void toggleFloating() {
        parentDockWidget->setFloating(!parentDockWidget->isFloating());
    }

    void closeParent() {
        parentDockWidget->toggleViewAction()->setChecked(false);
        parentDockWidget->hide();
    }

protected:
    void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent*  ) override{
        startEdit();
    }
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* e) override {
        e->ignore();
    }
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* e) override {
        e->ignore();
    }
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* e) override {
        e->ignore();
    }

private:
    QLabel* titleLabel;
    QLineEdit* titleEdit;
    QToolButton* dockButton;
    QToolButton* closeButton;
    QDockWidget* parentDockWidget;
};
```

Comment: (1) This won't work, because `titleBarWidget()` does not return the default widget. (2) As the docs you linked to made clear, this will be *much* more difficult to implement than the rest of your explanation suggests.

Comment: correct about the titleBarWidget(), I guess it's clear I didn't even try it. But for (2), the docs don't suggest anything which is difficult to implement. The only compulsory thing I didn't mention is explicitly ignoring `QMouseEvent`s, but since he is dealing with double clicks, he already needs a mouse event handler, Other than that, default sizeHint() is fine, and he can choose not to support a vertical title bar. Overall, i'd say it is an intermediate level task, not one for a beginner, but I did say it is "quite involved".

Comment: Actually, mouse events are forwarded to the QDockWidget itself, so you can use an event filter on it directly

Comment: @ekhumoro i've addressed what you said in the above comments (sorry for not tagging there, new to this site), and made a few edits/added an example. Is that any better?

Comment: Looks good! I have added a community wiki answer with a pyqt4 port of your code. Note that `windowTitleChanged` is only available in Qt5 (I used an event-filter instead). I also tweaked the double-click handling so that the normal behaviour is preserved. (PS: when I said "much more difficult", I meant for the OP - who I assume is fairly new to pyqt and probably doesn't know much c++).